# Getting an error trying to set conditional breakpoint using StackTrace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, .net-core

I am trying to set up a conditional breakpoint using this expression:

```cs
new System.Diagnostics.StakTrace().ToString().Contains("SetupValidity")
```

But it always errors out with:

```
The following breakpoint cannot be set:

(redacted) when 'new System.Diagnostics.StakTrace().ToString().Contains("SetupValidity")' is true

The condition for a breakpoint failed to execute. 
The condition was 'new System.Diagnostics.StakTrace().ToString().Contains("SetupValidity")'. 
The error returned was 'Evaluation of method System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString requires calling method 
System.Reflection.MethodBase.get_MethodImplementationFlags, which cannot be called in this context.'
```

Searching around, I found two suggestions:

- Checking (and restarting VS) `Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Use Managed Compatibility Mode`
- Checking (in Project properties) `Enable native code debugging`

Tried enabling these feratures separately, simultaneously.. no change.

Tools:

- `.NET Core 3.1`
- `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 16.8.5`

How do I fix this?

[image: error in picture]

Answer (score 1):

The error message makes it pretty clear that you can't "fix" this; if you really need that break condition, you'll need to change the code, and evaluate the `new System.Diagnostics.StakTrace().ToString()` in regular compiled code, then perform any test/break that you choose.